# Why is my flash movie terminating with the message "Test Movie terminated" immidiately after launch in Flash CC 2015?

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flash, creative-cloud

Since updating to Flash CC 2015 my flash project is terminating just after initializing. This is not happening in CC 2014, and no error messages are printed.

Comment: Turn on debug mode and test again. You should receive a fatal error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using AIR:
I had this very same issue, and the cause was AIR version I had defined in my project-app.xml.

I used to use AIR 16, and due to custom definitions in xml I needed to turn it to read-only mode so that Flash wouldn't overwrite it. Now when I updated to CC 2015, AIR 17 came along with it and I needed to update AIR version in xml too.

If this is not your case, it's probably something similar very simple.